# RegEx to make sure that the string contains at least one lower case char, upper case char, digit and symbol

Tags: regex

What is the regex to make sure that a given string contains at least one character from each of the following categories.

- Lowercase character
- Uppercase character
- Digit
- Symbol

I know the patterns for individual sets namely `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `\d` and `_|[^\w]` (I got them correct, didn't I?).

But how do I combine them to make sure that the string contains all of these in any order?

Comment: What platform/regex-dialect? Bart's answer is right, but lookahead assertions aren't reliable in JavaScript, for example.

Comment: Nowhere in particular - I'm learning regex. Is there an alternative that can be used in javascript?

Comment: @bobince Hey, I am trying to find out why lookahead assertions aren't reliable in Javascript. Is there a writeup on this?

Comment: @ChrisB: There's a really confusing IE/JScript bug: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug

Answer (score 462, accepted):

If you need one single regex, try:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)
```

A short explanation:

```
(?=.*[a-z])        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one lower case letter exists
(?=.*[A-Z])        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one upper case letter exists
(?=.*\d)           // use positive look ahead to see if at least one digit exists
(?=.*\W)           // use positive look ahead to see if at least one non-word character exists
```

And I agree with SilentGhost, `\W` might be a bit broad. I'd replace it with a character set like this: `[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]` (feel free to add more of course!)

Comment: What would happen if i change the last `.+` into `.*`? I couldn't come up with a test case that fails with `.*`. Are they same in this context? "Zero or more characters" seems to be fine - just seeking confirmation.

Comment: @Amarghosh: in this case, it makes no difference. Because of the positive look-aheads, the string already contains at least 4 characters. So it makes no difference to change `.+` into `.*` or even `.{4,}` for that matter.

Comment: If you would be willing to add a little explanation, I am having trouble understanding how the combination of these lookaheads guarantees at least 1 of each character set will be present

Comment: @Sharlike, I don't know how to rephrase it in order to make it easier to understand. Especially in these small comment-boxes. I recommend you read this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and if you still have question, simply post a question of your own. Good luck!

Comment: @BartKiers What if I don't want any symbol? removing `(?=.*[_\W])` doesn't work http://regex101.com/r/jH9rK1/1

Comment: @ikertxu, try something like this: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*[&%$]).{6,}$`

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks,is it possible to achieve a similar regex with minimum count. ex: 2 uppercase, 2 lowercase, 2 numeric & specific special character (%aAa1A2$) should be valid. sorry, Tried many solution but not to able to achieve.. I tried the following modified RegEx of your ^(?=.*[a-z]{2})(?=.*[A-Z]{2})(?=.*\d{2})(?=.*([%]{2})).{8,10}$.

Comment: How to make a strict check for each of the above along with the condition that an alphabet should be in the start followed by a number ending with a special character finally?

Comment: @RamachandraAPai comments are not well suited for asking (or answering) questions. Feel free to create a question of your own.

Comment: In my case was atlest 1 lower, atleast 1 upper, atleast 1 digit OR 1 symbol and min length 8.
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*(\d|\W)).{8,}

Comment: The example contains `(?=.*\W)` while the explanation contains `(?=.*\W])`. I think maybe the explanation has a typo - a rogue `]`?

Comment: @devklick yes, that `]` should't be there

Answer (score 45):

Bart Kiers, your regex has a couple issues. The best way to do that is this:

```
(.*[a-z].*)       // For lower cases
(.*[A-Z].*)       // For upper cases
(.*\d.*)          // For digits
(.*\W.*)          // For symbols (non-word characters)
```

In this way you are searching no matter if at the beginning, at the end or at the middle. In your have I have a lot of troubles with complex passwords.

Comment: You're not checking for symbols as the OP requested.

Comment: This will only wotk if lower case, upper case and digit are found in this order. For example ist does not work with 111aaqBBB

Answer (score 14):

[Bart Kiers solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559788/14081018) is good but it misses rejecting strings having *spaces* and accepting strings having *underscore* (`_`) as a symbol.

Improving on the Bart Kiers solution, here's the regex:

`(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])((?=.*\W)|(?=.*_))^[^ ]+$`

A short explanation:

```
(?=.*[a-z])        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one lower case letter exists
(?=.*[A-Z])        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one upper case letter exists
(?=.*\d)           // use positive look ahead to see if at least one digit exists
(?=.*\W)           // use positive look ahead to see if at least one non-word character exists
(?=.*_)           // use positive look ahead to see if at least one underscore exists
|           // The Logical OR operator
^[^ ]+$           // Reject the strings having spaces in them.
```

Side note: You can try test cases on a regex expression [here](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: Why reject on space? If this is for the password, space should be also included as per [OWASP recommendations](https://owasp.org/www-community/password-special-characters)

Comment: @Janusz'Ivellios'Kamieński Yes, you're right. But the application I was creating at that time required to reject spaces from passwords. Anyways, to allow spaces, simply remove this from the regex: `^[^ ]+$`

Comment: Got it... just a side note :)

Answer (score 6):

You can match those three groups separately, and make sure that they all present. Also, `[^\w]` seems a bit too broad, but if that's what you want you might want to replace it with `\W`.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of \W. Just looked it up to find that it matches Not Word. Is there any difference between \W and [\W]? Is [\W] just redundant?

Comment: @Amarghosh, yes, `\W` and `[\W]` result in the same.