# Why am I getting illegal escape characters with regexp in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a simply password strength checker and i can not success applying regular expressions. In different resources different kinds of regular expressions are defined.
i also find javascript regular expressions but had some problems to adapt.

First, these are the regular expressions i need for **JAVA**:

- at least one lower case letter
- at least one upper case letter at least
- one number  at least three numbers at
- least one special character at least
- two special characters both letters
- and numbers both upper and lower case
- letters, numbers, and special characters

My goal is not being a regular expression expert i just want to use the parts i need.If you direct me good tutorials which discusses above for **java**, will be appreciated.

Second, in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper-c) some of them are mentioned but i'm getting problems to apply them.

here does not catch the lower case letter (my pass: A5677a)

> if (passwd.matches("(?=.*[a-z])"))      // [verified] at least one lower case letter
>   {Score = Score+5;}

Also here i'm getting error : illegal escape character.

> if (passwd.matches("(?=.*\d)"))   // [verified] at least one number

Finally, are these expressions all different in different kind of programming or script languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the first regex (`"(?=.*[a-z])"`) is that you are trying to match a sequence that ends with `a-z`; the `*` applies to the `.`, which overall says "match anything, then end with a letter from `a` to `z`."

To pass a literal backslash, you need to escape it as such: `"(?=.*\\d)"`.

The illegal escape sequence is because Java tries to process the escape sequences in the string before it gets passed to the regex - `\d` does not map to anything, as opposed to `\t` or `\n` which map to tab and newline.

To help streamline your development process with regular expressions, I would suggest using a tool such as [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) that will allow you to test your regexes before you compile the program, so that you can see the results in real time.  There are also online resources such as [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Based on the problems you're having, it wouldn't hurt to try running through some regular expression tutorials, either.

Comment: To clarify this, you are trying to push a backslash (as escape character) into a regex, via Java's string handling (which also uses backslash as escape character).  Therefore you need to escape it to get it past Java's string handling.

Comment: i tried that and it didn't work 
if ( passwd.matches ("(?=.*\\d)") )  doesn't catch any numbers in my password.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the amount of regular expressions you need, maybe it's time for you to become a regular expression expert. Check out the tutorial on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), that's what taught me regexp.

Comment: thanks for the tutorial, i have to learn these.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a regular expression in this case would be pretty inefficient.  A regular expression is not going to keep track of how many xs, ys, and zs you have (where x, y, and z are whatever criteria you list above) - this means you will need to apply multiple regular expressions (as you are doing in your example), each of which can take up to linear time.

Why not just write a processing function that examines every character in your password instead?  You can do your entire check in a single pass.

Partial example:

```
public boolean isStrong(String toCheck) {
    boolean hasLower = false;
    boolean hasUpper = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < toCheck.length(); i++) {
      char next = toCheck.charAt(i);
      if (Character.isLower(next)) {
        hasLower = true;
      } else if (Character.isUpper(next)) {
        hasUpper = true;
      }
    }

    return hasLower && hasUpper;
}
```

**Edit**: I just noticed you are calculating a score rather than checking weak vs. strong; this can easily be adapted accordingly.

Comment: Yes, i also think these function. i can adapt but i have to use regular expressions. thanks.