# RegEx to validate a string, whether it contains at least one lower case char, upper case char, one digit,one symbol and no whitespace

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx to make sure that the string contains at least one lower case char, upper case char, digit and symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper-c)

What would be the regex to make sure that a given string contains at least one character from each of the followings ---

- upper case letter
- lower case letter
- no whitespace
- digit
- symbol
- string length is >=5 and <=10

how to combine all these above criteria to validate a string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it has to be a regex:

```
^            # Start of string
(?=.*[A-Z])  # upper case (ASCII) letter
(?=.*[a-z])  # lower case letter
(?=.*\d)     # digit
(?=.*[\W_])  # symbol
\S           # no whitespace
{5,10}       # string length is >=5 and <=10
$            # end of string
```

or, if your regex flavor doesn't support verbose regexes:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\W_])\S{5,10}$
```