# How to validate a string which contains at least one letter and one digit in javascript?

Tags: javascript

It doesn't matter how many letters and digits, but string should contain both.

Jquery function `$('#sample1').alphanumeric()` will validate given string is alphanumeric or not. I, however, want to validate that it contains both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx to make sure that the string contains at least one lower case char, upper case char, digit and symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper-c)

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear: does the string need to be alphanumeric? Or would '#sample1' be valid?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So you want to check two conditions. While you could use one complicated regular expression, it's better to use two of them:

```
if (/\d/.test(string) && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(string)) {
```

This makes your program more readable and may even perform slightly better (not sure about that though).

Comment: if((/\d/.test(string) || /[a-zA-Z]/.test(string)) === false) {
 alert('Field has no Alphanumeric characters.');
}

Answer (score 2):

```
/([0-9].*[a-z])|([a-z].*[0-9])/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex you need

```
^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Za-z])\w*$
```

and this link explains how you'd use it

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions

```
/^[A-z0-9]+$/g //defines captial a-z and lowercase a-z then numbers 0 through nine


function isAlphaNum(s){ // this function tests it
p = /^[A-z0-9]+$/g;
return p.test(s);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure that you have a digit _and_ a letter does it?  Just that you have at least one of either.