# I need a Perl script to find at least one uppercase, one lowercase, one special char, one digit and one whitespace in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I  want a script to select a username. The rules for selecting a username are

- The minimum length of the username is 5 characters and the maximum is 10
- It should contain at least one letter from A-Z
- It should contain at least one digit from 0-9
- It should contain at least one character from amongst @#*=
- It should not contain any spaces.

I have tried this

```
if ( length $passwd[$i] <= 10
    && length $passwd[$i] >= 5
    && $passwd[$i] =~ /.*\p{Lu}/
    && $passwd[$i] =~ tr/0-9//cd
    && $passwd[$i] =~ /[a-z]/ ) {

  print "PASS\n";
}
else {
  print "FAIL\n";
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem with what you have written? It doesn't look like a real attempt to write your own solution to me. Where is your attempt to check for the symbols? Why have you used `/.*\p{Lu}/` for the upper case letter, `/[a-z]/` for the lower case letter, and `tr/0-9//cd` for the digit? And why is your *username* called `$passwd[$i]`? Please make a reasonable attempt to do your own work and we will help you if you get stuck.

Comment: Lot's of **regex** questions on the topic of [strong passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[regex]%20strong%20password).

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx to make sure that the string contains at least one lower case char, upper case char, digit and symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get below Regex using lookarounds. I tried many examples to test it and seems like it is working as per your conditions. In case it does not work for any pattern, then let me know.

```
echo eff*sdE8ff | perl -n -e 'print if /^(?=.{5,10}$)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*[@#*=])(?!.*\s+)/'
```

**UPDATE:**
After reading OP's comment...

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my @passwd = ('eff*sdE8ff', 'eff*sde8ff');

foreach (@passwd)
{
    if ($_ =~ /^(?=.{5,10}$)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*[@#*=])(?!.*\s+)/)
    {
        print "PASS: $_ \n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "FAIL \n";
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
PASS: eff*sdE8ff 
FAIL
```

Comment: thank you sir. its working in command promt. but how can i use it in my script. i am like two days old in perl. so please be co-operative. i know i somehow asking very silly question..

Comment: @Ricky, check the updated answer above.

Comment: thank you so much sir. but its printing the string which contains a whitespace..

Comment: @Ricky, I have updated the regex. try now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slighty more readable alternative for a novice user:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name = $ARGV[0];

if((length($name)<5 || length($name)>10) ||
   ($name !~ /[A-Z]/)  ||
   ($name !~ /[0-9]/)  ||
   ($name !~ /[@#*=]/) ||
   ($name =~ / /)){
   print "FAIL\n";
} else {
   print "PASS\n";
}
```