# Input text custom validation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

There is the following code:

```
<input class="form-control" id="secret_key" type="text" name="secret_key" ng-model="hotel.secret_key" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="8" placeholder="Secret Key" />
```

I can validation length of this field, it works. But now I have to validate if this length contains at least one digit, one small letter and one capital letter. How can I do it using AngularJS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see if you get something from this http://jsfiddle.net/adamdbradley/Qdk5M/

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a simple `RegExp` validation pattern on the input model via `ng-pattern` as follows:

```
<input ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$/" name="text" type="text" ng-model="formData">
```

This will validate that the input contains at least *1 lowercase character*, *1 uppercase character* and *1 integer*.

[Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uVsqpqq3enDthc2jOMlS?p=preview) for you to try out the above code.

If you're interested in understanding the RegExp pattern, [here is the breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper).