# Missing few characters from regex string, when passing it through an external application to the WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, regex, string, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I've two get methods in my WebAPI, which are:

1. `CheckPassword(string Password, string regExp)` //to validate password pattern, takes password and the regular expression.
2. `CheckEmailValid(string Email, string regExp)` //to validate email pattern, takes email and its regular expression.

When I try to call a Get method in WebAPI by passing two strings(password, regExp) OR (email, regExp) using a console app, some of the character miss out from the string. But at the same time if I have the regular expression in my WebAPI and test, it works fine. So I miss few character somewhere between the application and the webAPI.

**Original Regex string for Password**

```
public const string passwordPattern = @"^(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{7,}$";
```

**The string which I receive at WebAPI Method while debugging**

```
{^(?=.*[0-9] .*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z] .*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{7,}$}
```

Here I'm missing out + symbol, thats why password validation fails all the time.

**Original Regex string for Email**

```
public const string emailPattern = @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z";
```

**The string which I receive at WebAPI Method while debugging**

```
\\A(?:[a-z0-9!
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for first `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{7,}$` will suffice

Comment: Shud take atleast one Capital letter. but it accepts if there is no capital letter

Comment: in that case use:- `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{7,}$`..for at least one uppercase, one lowercase and one digit

Comment: While the regex really does not need any `+` quantifier, it is interesting what to do if the `+` quantifier *is* necessary. I think there is some Uri escaping in your code. Otherwise, it can be closed as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Performing URL Encoding actually solved my issue**

While sending from APP to API, URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings. Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash mark (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers. As a result, these characters must be encoded in  tags or in query strings where the strings can be re-sent by a browser in a request string.
This method is a convenient way to access the HttpUtility.UrlEncode method at run time from an ASP.NET application. Internally, this method uses HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode strings. So, encode the regex string using HttpUtility.UrlEncode.

```
string urlEncodedPwdPattern = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(passwordPattern)
```

Pass the string to API.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Credential/CheckPassword?password=" + password + "&regExp=" + urlEncodedPwdPattern).ConfigureAwait(true);
```