# Password Testing in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code to test a password for strength:

```
import string
def golf(password):
    if len(password) >= 10:
        if any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
            if any(string.punctuation for char in password):
                if any(char.isalpha() for char in password):
                    if any(char.isupper() for char in password):
                        if any(char.islower() for char in password):
                            return True
    return False
```

I know it can be done better!  It needs to test for the following ...

The password will be considered strong enough if it
has at least 10 characters
contains at least one digit
contains at least one uppercase letter
contains at least one lowercase letter. The password may only contain ASCII Latin letters or digits, but *no* punctuation symbols.

**EDIT**

OK for anyone else i got it down to the following with regex.

```
import re
def golf(password):
    return re.match( r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.{10,30}).+$', password)
```

Apparently it can still be shorter...

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `and`?

Comment: `if any(string.punctuation for char in password):` looks wrong

Comment: Have you considered a regex match?

Comment: I understand this might just be an exercise, but it you really are using this with people's security, please consider using a library like **zxcvbn**. It's what they use at DropBox. There's even a Python port https://github.com/dwolfhub/zxcvbn-python.  It's designed specifically to foil pw crackers, which is difficult.

Comment: If you want to go the regex route that @DavidHoelzer mentions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1559751/4996248

Comment: Anyone have an example of the regex i would use? This seems likely to be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you're quite close.  Yes, you have a variety of conditions to check; the rules *are* that complication.  Note that you don't have to check for `alpha`: the checks for `islower` and `isupper` cover that.  You can make this just a little easier to handle by putting the rules into a single expression:

```
import string
def golf(password):
    return \
        len(password) >= 10                              and \
        any(char.isdigit() for char in password)         and \
        not any(string.punctuation for char in password) and \
        any(char.isupper() for char in password)         and \
        any(char.islower() for char in password)
```

Note that you're evaluating a Boolean expression: just return that value.  There's no need to say

```
if <expr>:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

You already *have* the value in hand; just return it.

Comment: I think it should be `all(char not in string.punctuation`

Comment: This answer was useful , thanks! I still think it can be done shorter though.. maybe regex?

Comment: Yes -- as you found, you can make it shorter with regex.  "Better" is a value judgment.  I wrote only to improve your existing approach, keeping the simplicity and readability.

Answer (score 0):

That's one long string of if statements XD. You should just use some and statements.

```
if len(password) >= 10 and any(char.isdigit() for char in password)...:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

The else statement is not necessary, as you know, but it makes the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks for that , Yes it is shortened if you use and statements but harder to read also , i believe it can be readable and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The more optimal way would be to do your character checking all in one loop.

```
import string
def golf(password):
    if len(password) < 10:
      return False

    saw_digit = saw_upper = saw_lower = False
    no_punct = all_alnum = True

    for char in password:
      saw_digit = saw_digit or char.isdigit()
      saw_upper = saw_upper or char.isupper()
      saw_lower = saw_lower or char.islower()
      no_punct = no_punct and (char not in string.punctuation)
      all_alnum = all_alnum and char.isalnum()

    values = [saw_digit, saw_lower, saw_upper, no_punct, all_alnum]
    # print(values)
    return all(values)
```