# Setting regex pattern for mongoengine 0.9.0 StringField

Tags: python, regex, django, pymongo, mongoengine

I use python 2.7.12 with pymongo 2.8.1, django 1.11.7, mongoengine 0.9.0 and mongodb 3.4.10.
I am creating a custom user model which inserts documents in a regular mongodb collection. I inherited the 'Document' class from mongoengine to create the string password field. I've been trying to create a regex pattern for the following conditions:

- Length: 8-25 characters
- At least 1 uppercase letter
- At least 1 lowercase letter
- At least 1 number
- At least 1 special character

I tried using re.compile() in the following way:

```
import re
regexp = re.compile('[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]', max_length=25, min_length=8)
password = StringField(regex=regexp)
```

I sent HTTP POST requests with invalid passwords and it only throws an error when the length is lesser than 8 or greater than 25, otherwise they pass.
I'm new to mongoengine and I'm not really sure what kind of input the regex parameter takes, neither have I been able to find examples for StringField. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the conditions for "must have 1 number, 1 lowercase, 1 upper case 1 special)" - you could model that with lookaheads. Look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html   for `(?=...)` - you probably need smth like "(?=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])(?=[0-9])(?=[@#$%^&+=])[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]*}

Comment: Probably this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper

Comment: You can also check out [Django Regex Validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#regexvalidator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,25}$
```

You can try this.Each condition is added using lookahead.Add more special characters if you want.

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/fDS1wI/1)