# Filtering Regex Uppercase and number 0

Tags: regex

I need a Regex which matches a string of `uppercase` characters of exactly 48 characters length and `mandatory number 0` in it (1 or more times).

I would like to use it to filter these strings.

For example:

quick brown fox AUSGKAJDGAYGDKJAS**0**GDKJAGDJKASGDKJASGDKYQGWUDVAS**0** jumped over the fence

Comment: Most dialects support `[A-Z]{48}0*`, did you really not google before asking? See also the [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) which tells you what you need to include in your question. Also, 0 is not mandatory if zero repetitions is acceptable.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. This matches 48 chars without 0. I need it to match if string _contains_ **0**

Comment: Then you don't mean "zero or more" really. Please review the tag guidance and [edit] your question so it's answerable.

Comment: Maybe you mean `[A-Z0]{48}` then?

Comment: Fixed it, I am sorry. I obviously meant **1 or more times**

Comment: ```[A-Z0]{48}``` Matches with or without 0, sadly

Comment: Try this [`(?=^[A-Z0]{48}$)([A-Z0]*0[A-Z0]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/xnqXsD/1). Edit : Nevermind, you want to match this string inside a sentence, gonna fix this.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Works very well. Please post this as answer so I can mark it as accepted answer. 
EDIT: sorry I didn't check if it matches inside a sentence.

Comment: There's a ton of questions like this already, what have you tried and where are you stuck? Try e.g. something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper or generally any password validation regex question (though using regex for that is usually not a good idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches your desired pattern :

```
(?=\b.{48}\b)[A-Z0]*0[A-Z0]*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xnqXsD/3).

**Explanation :**

- The first part of the regex `(?=\b.{48}\b)` ensures that the full match will be of exactly 48 characters
- The second part `[A-Z0]*0[A-Z0]*` is the actual pattern, matching any uppercase character or 0 and making sure at least one 0 is inside.

Comment: Hey Paul, I would like to use it also in Google Docs, and I just learned their Regex (RE2) doesn't support positive lookaheads. I searched for replacement for re2 but it seems it's not possible. Can you think of any other solution without usage of positive lookaheads? Thanks

Comment: I can't think of a way of doing it without positive lookahead, sorry :x