# validate a password using regex followed by a pattern

Tags: jquery

we need to check if the security password is documented correctly for an Internal Web CRM.

**Is there a way to validate a given security password like a `"$$$$Addy1234"`?**

This password string contains 4 Special Char, 4 Alphabets and 4 Number.And Alphabets part should contain one Upper and one Lower Case Character.

The regex I tried that work with all the case but in the Alphabets, I need to get at least one Upper and one Lower Case Character.

**I tried following but can't get a solution:**

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function () {

    if ($("#txt_pasword").filter(function () {
        return this.value.match(/^([-\/@#!*$%^&.'_+={}()]{4})([a-zA-Z]{4})([0-9]{4})$/);
    })) {
        $("#txt_pasword").parent().child("span").text("pass");
    } else {
        $("#txt_pasword").parent().child("span").text("fail");
    }

});
```

Please provide an idea how should I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Addy.Please read through this and see if this helps ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper/1559788

Comment: I don't understand what you want here? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Liam actually I want a regex which validates this string contains case as I provide in my Question there all the case I match except the Alphabets part which contains at least one lower and one upper case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx to all people who provide me solution for this problem mainly @kalaiselvan-a and @ronnie-oosting.

But from the idea @kalaiselvan-a give than approximately correct with few of issue but this one helps me to get the solution accordingly.

Used Regex is :

**`/^([-\/@#!*$%^&.'_+={}()]{4})((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]{4})([0-9]{4})$/`**

**1st Capturing Group** `([-\/@#!*$%^&.'_+={}()]{4})` Matches exactly 4 times character in the list `@#!*$%^&.'_+={}()` (case sensitive)

**2nd Capturing Group** `((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]{4})` Matches exactly 4 times character in the list `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` with one of each

**3rd Capturing Group** `([0-9]{4})` Matches exactly 4 times a character present in the list `[0-9]{4}`

Answer (score 2):

In the below code you can use your own logic for display error message but here I used alert

```js
$(function(){
    $("#btn_submit").click(function () {
        var mat_str=/^([-\/@#!*$%^&.'_+={}()]{4})((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{4,})([0-9]{4})$/;
        var pass=$("#txt_pasword").val();
          if(pass!=null && pass!=undefined){
              if(mat_str.test(pass)){
              alert("pass");                
              }else{
              alert("fails");
              }
          }else{
              alert("Please Enter password");
          }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<input type="password" id="txt_pasword">
<span></span>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn_submit" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: this also not work if the string does not contain an upper or lower char.

Comment: @addy it will work based on your regexp `/^([-\/@#!*$%^&.'_+={}()]{4})([a-zA-Z]{4})([0-9]{4})$/` i taken this from your question based on your try

Comment: sorry buddy also have an issue with alphabets part this also provides a match if the string does not contain an upper or lower case char.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help you?

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = "$$$$Addy1234";
    var res = str.substring(0,3);
    var res2 = str.substring(4,7);
    var res3 = str.substring(8, 11);
    var check = 0;
    // check special chars
    if (res.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/))
    {
        check += 1;
    }

    // check upper/lower cases
    if (res2.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))
    {
        check += 1;
    }

    // check numbers
    if (res3.match(/([0-9])/))
    {
        check += 1;
    }

    if( check < 3)
    {
        // return false
    }

    if (check === 3)
    {
        // return true
    }
});
```

You can make different checks:

```
// If password contains both lower and uppercase characters, increase strength value.
        if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) strength += 1
// If it has numbers and characters, increase strength value.
        if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/)) strength += 1
// If it has one special character, increase strength value.
        if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
// If it has two special characters, increase strength value.
        if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
```

You can check your own regex based on what given.

Using `substring` you can check specific length with a start and end.

**Will this do it for you?** Let me know! :)

Comment: Good try boy but there I have an issue with a password with a specific count of chars.This works individual like my tried regex but not accomplish my task

Comment: So if I understood it correctly: You need to check the first 4 chars, the next 4 and the last 4 (in your situation)?

Comment: Do you know about charAt and substring?

Comment: Yes, But this not an answer and suggestion for my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161443/discussion-between-addy-and-ronnie-oosting).

Comment: @addy ive edited my answer. I see you left the chat, perhaps this help you. Let me know man