# Regex to validate parameters in the URI

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to validate URIs of the system with regex to identify parameters in the middle of the URI of a REST API, however, I'm having problems with parameter validation at the end of the URI, for example:

In the database I get the rule for URI: `/uaa/api/users/*/city/*`

Replace the '*' with the regex so that it accepts any character between / or after /: `^/uaa/api/users/+(.*)+/city/+(.*)$`

I compare the URI with regex with the request URI: `/uaa/api/users/john.connor/city/12`

But if I remove the value at the end of the URI and leave only the / it accepts being that I need it to fail because there is no value after /, that is, when using the `^/uaa/api/users/+(.*)+/city/+(.*)$` regex with the `/uaa/api/users/john.connor/city/` URI I need it to fail because there is no value after /.How can I do it so he does not accept a worthless bar followed in the end?

I do not know if that matters, but I'm using regex in Java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to note about the pattern that you are using.

The plus in `/+` is a quantifier in this context matching 1+ times a forward slash. This part `(.*)+` also uses that quantifier to repeat a group that itself matches 0+ times any character (inclusing the forward slash).

I think what you are looking for is to match not a forward slash using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refshorthand.html) `[^/]+` between the forward slashes and for the last part as well so that the url can not end on a forward slash.

```
^/uaa/api/users/[^/]+/city/[^/]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OSo4iX/1)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper)

This contains at least one character from each of the following categories.

Lowercase character
Uppercase character
Digit
Symbol

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)

(?=.*[a-z])        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one lower case letter exists
(?=.*[A-Z])        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one upper case letter exists
(?=.*\d)           // use positive look ahead to see if at least one digit exists
(?=.*\W])        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one non-word character exists
```