# Regular expression, X out of Y critereon to match

Tags: python, regex

My question stems from an old one (link): [RegEx to make sure that the string contains at least one lower case char, upper case char, digit and symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper)

I've been playing around with REGEX/PYTHEX and stumbled upon this I could not figure out. 
How do we make it so 3 of the 4 categories are satisfied instead of all four? Would it be possible to use only regular expressions?

Just to re-iterate, the REGEX aforementioned is:
`(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)`

Contains ALL of the following: At least 1 **Digit**, At least 1 **Lowercase**, At least 1 **Uppercase**, At least 1 **Special character**

INTO

Contains 3 AT LEAST of the following: At least 1 **Digit**, At least 1 **Lowercase**, At least 1 **Uppercase**, At least 1 **Special character**

Comment: You can sort the string and then do `r'(?:\W+\d+[A-Z]+)|(?:\W+\d+[a-z]+)|(?:\W+[A-Z]+[a-z]+)|(?:\d+[A-Z]+[a-z]+)'` but it's ugly solution.

Comment: Match one condition and use lookaheads for the remaining three conditions. Yes, ugly maybe? [`^(?=(?:\D*\d){3})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})(?:\w*\W){3}`](https://regex101.com/r/G6kq4Z/1/)