# Regex Sequence Strong Password

Tags: python, regex

I would like to test if the input value meets the criterias:

- at least one lower case letter
- at least one upper case letter
- at least one digit
- at least one character that is non \w

It seems the regex I programmed only follows this specific order like:
abCD99$%

But if I shuffled the sequence, the regex doesn't work anymore:
CD99ab$%

Anyone knows what the problem is please? Cheers in advance.

```
import re

# Asks user for an input

print('Please enter a password for checking its strength:')

pwd = input('> ')

#Test the input to see if it is more than 8 characters

if not len(pwd) < 8:
    pwdRegex = re.compile(r'([a-z]+)([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)(\W+)')     #order problem
    if not pwdRegex.search(pwd) == None:
        print('Password OK.')
    else:
        print('Please make sure password fulfills requirements!')
else:
    print('Characters must not be less than 8 characters!')
```

Comment: Using positive lookaheads right would solve that issue. I recon there are quite some examples out there on SO.

Comment: It's much easier to use a separate regex for each of those criteria.

Comment: Please refer to this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper

Comment: @Thomas only if you're not familiar with regex :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of lookaheads to verify your requirements:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W)^.+$
```

- `(?=.*[a-z])` - make sure we have a lowercase char somewhere
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - make sure we have an uppercase char somewhere
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - make sure we have a digit somewhere
- `(?=.*\W)` - make sure we have a non-`\w` somewhere
- `^.+$` - all the aforementioned requirements were met so lets capture the entire line

  - This piece can be omitted if you're just doing a pass/fail test and don't need to capture anything

https://regex101.com/r/HdfVXp/1/

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think it could be a good solution to make your validation without regex:

```py
def isGoodPassword(password):
  # contains upper and lower, digit and special char
  return (not password.islower()
         and not password.isupper()
         and any(c.isdigit() for c in password) 
         and any(not c.isalnum() for c in password))


isGoodPassword('hello') # False
isGoodPassword('Hello!') # False
isGoodPassword('Hello!1') # True
```

Answer (score -1):

The https://pypi.org/project/password-strength/ package contains code to do this. If you are interested in how this is done rather than actually doing it you could read the source code.